# How to convert for loop generated data into Data Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have extracted data from a table in a website with for-loop using
selenium automation webdriver. How to convert that data into dataframe
and export to csv file. I tried to assign the 'value' within pandas dataframe but it is throwing error.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.jambalakadi.info/status/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)

row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(" //*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody[1]/tr "))
col_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(" //*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td "))

print('Number of row counts:', row_count)
print("Number of column counts:", col_count)


for r in range(2, row_count+1):
    for c in range(1, col_count+1):
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody[1]/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"] ").text
        print(value, end=" ")

    print(" ")
```

[image]

when I run the for-loop the 'value' variable printing the data but I'm
not able to create data frame and export it to CSV file using pandas.

I updated the code is it correctly formatted?

```
my_data = []
for r in range(2, row_count+1):
    for c in range(1, col_count+1):
        value = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //*[@id='main_table_countries_today']/tbody[1]/tr["+str(r)+"]/td["+str(c)+"] ").text
        print(value, end=" ")
        for line in value:
            my_data.append(line[0],line[1],line[2])
        pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_data, columns=column).to_csv('output.csv')

    print(" ")
```

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: I didn't mention website url as I'm scraping data without website permission.

Comment: Ok.In that case you need to post html of the table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code using pandas to get data in `dataframe` and then import to csv.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://yourwebsitename.com")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#main_table_countries_today")))
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
table=soup.find('table',attrs={"id":"main_table_countries_today"})
df=pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df[0])
df[0].to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

**Updated**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://yourwebsitename.com")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table#main_table_countries_today")))
table=driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].outerHTML;",element)
df=pd.read_html(str(table))
print(df[0])
df[0].to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: This code should be added to my code or this is entirely a different one? as I'm getting error :                                                                                                                                 
" The code that caused this warning is on line 13 of the file /home/user/PycharmProjects/seleniumScrape/testing.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP}) "

Comment: @Jainmiah :You need to add parser to avoid warnings I have added the parser.However i have posted one more solution without beautiful soup.Let me know how it goes?

Comment: First one worked fine @KunduK thank you so much , actually I'm a beginner eagerly want to learn about this selenium. How can learn so that I get clear Idea write like above code?

Comment: there is tab available like now and yesterday can I extract both at once with automation using selenium?

Comment: To get the value of yesterday You need to click on the tab first by selenium and then you can get the value.

Comment: I tried but I'm getting stored same values as "now" tab in "output.csv" and "output1.csv"

Comment: Sorry I am away now.I’ll come back tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @KunduK I solved it completely and can remove or change the website name in the code that you answered as this may be an issue in future.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function `pd.DataFrame.from_records()`

Use case:

```
import pandas as pd
#Reading the data
my_data = []
for line in my_database:
    #preprocess the line (say you get 3 columns date,customer,price)
    #say you use line.split(" "), now your line is actually an array of values (line = line.split(" ")
    my_data.append([line[0],line[1],line[2]]) #each index corresponds to date, customer and price respectively

pd.DataFrame.from_records(my_data, columns=['date','customer','price']).to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: if there are 100 lines then should I manually mention line[0],line[1],line[2] or anyother way to fix it.

Comment: ... No. line[0] line[1] line[2] stand for the values that you get, i.e. you transform an entire line read into an array of values, and line[0] == array_of_values[0], line[1] == array_of_values[1] etc.

Comment: It says out of range